# Reset but not truncate

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any possible way to reset a record in a table, without truncating it?

Here is my table:

[image: table stack]

So, i want to reset the stack_number back to A-1 without deleting the previous record

Comment: reset for what ? why you can not use delete (`delete from table where id = '2'`) ?

Comment: What does the 'reset' mean here? You'd better post the input and output directly. Is this what you want: `update table set stack_number = 'A-1' where id = 2`?